# KnpSnappyBundle can't install in Symfony 5.1.7

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Hello i can´t install with Symfony 5.1.7.

C:\xampp\htdocs\engodi>composer require knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle
Using version ^1.8 for knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- Root composer.json requires knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle ^1.8 -> satisfiable by knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle[v1.8.0].
- knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle v1.8.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^4.4|^5.1 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.22, v5.1.0, ..., v5.2.7] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (5.0.*).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: It looks like your project has `symfony/framework-bundle` pinned to version 5.0. Can you run `composer show symfony/framework-bundle` to confirm this? You can run `composer require knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle --update-with-root-dependencies` (or `-W`, be careful `-w` and `-W` are slightly different) to update all dependencies you have already installed to match the requirements, but be careful to check what was updated to see if it might cause trouble

Comment: Hello. I run composer show symfony/framework-bundle and show me this...

C:\xampp\htdocs\engodi>composer show symfony/framework-bundle
name     : symfony/framework-bundle
descrip. : Symfony FrameworkBundle
keywords :
versions : * v5.0.11
type     : symfony-bundle
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
homepage : https://symfony.com
source   : [git] https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle.git 0fc0a93f8bbe465d0b483e21b087d432baa92c16
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/framework-bundle/zipball/0fc0a93....

Comment: if I run composer require knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle --update-with-root-dependencies show me this...

C:\xampp\htdocs\engodi>composer require knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle -W
Using version ^1.8 for knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle --with-all-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: For what it is worth, I made a new Symfony 5.2 project and then required the snappy bundle.  It all installed cleanly.  Might be time to generate a new composer.json file if you can't sort this out.

Comment: Can you show the composer file? Symfony used to have a limiter that prevents the packages from being accidentally upgraded somewhere in the extra section that is likely the cause. See: https://github.com/symfony/skeleton/blob/5.0/composer.json#L61

Comment: Hello, this is this is my composer.json. Thanks!!!!